# Como colocar nome de propriedade num Objeto JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, objetos

```
    js = {
        p1: {
            qq: "qq_val",
        },
        p2: [{
            qq: "qq_val",
        }]
    };


    json = JSON.stringify(js);
    console.log(json); // {"p1":{"qq":"qq_val"},"p2":[{"qq":"qq_val"}]}
```

Bom, eu queria apenas dar um nome a propriedade, para que não ficasse vazia, tentei algo como:

```
js = {
    p1: {
        qq: "qq_val",
    },
    p2: [prop_name:{ // aqui eu coloco o nome da propriedade.
        qq: "qq_val",
    }]
};


json = JSON.stringify(js);
console.log(json); // {"p1":{"qq":"qq_val"},"p2":[{"qq":"qq_val"}]}
```

mas acusa erro, veja: http://jsfiddle.net/61cmd6r3/

Talvez eu esteja embaralhando alguns conceitos (mesmo que básicos), espero uma luz de vocês para eu entender melhor, estou muito confuso..

Comment: O que queres fazer exatamente? Como o `p2:` recebe uma array, não dá para dar nomes...

Comment: Isso se chama: Erro de síntaxe :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Este é um objeto:

```
{qq: "qq_val"}
```

Possui um atributo, `qq`, cujo valor é a *string* `qq_val`. A notação está correta.

Esta é uma coleção com um único membro:

```
[{qq:"qq_val"}]
```

Uma coleção é determinada pelos colchetes (`[` e `]`), e a separação entre objetos membros da mesma coleção é feita com vírgulas, desta maneira:

```
[{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3},(...)]
```

Este é um objeto, que possui um atributo chamado `p2`, cujo valor é uma coleção:

```
{p2:[{qq:"qq_val"}]}
```

Todos estes objetos estão bem formados. Entretanto, sua tentativa de nomear um objeto ocorreu diretamente na coleção:

```
[prop_name:{ [...]
```

Coleções não possuem atributos, apenas uma lista de objetos.

Comment: Curti o jeito que explanou, me ajudou a entender melhor os conceitos.

Answer (score 2):

Estou vendo que você está tentando atribuir um atributo ao array como se ele fosse um objeto pelo seu exemplo.

```
[prop_name:{ [...]
```

Talvez algo que possa te ajudar, já que você está tendo dificuldades, seria vendo como se dá a declaração do objeto.

Primeiro monte ele linha por linha, pra depois ver como ficaria a declaração.Assim você pode comparar com o seu objeto e ver se tem algo de errado.

Exemplo:

```
js.p1 = {}

js.p2 = {}

js.p2.qq = "valor"

js.p1.qq = 'outro valor';
```

Aí você faz o seguinte pra ver a declaração:

```
JSON.stringify(js)

{"p1":{"qq":"outro valor"},"p2":{"qq":"valor"}}
```

Eu faria algo assim só pra ver onde estou errando :)

Comment: Boa sugestão, fazendo isso fica mais na cara que, o que eu estava fazendo, era de fato algo bizarro, rsrs.